# Python broke, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'python_version'

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pandas

I am running 2.7 on Windows. I had no problems until yesterday when I tried to run a few jobs using the `multiprocessing` library, got a bunch of memory errors, and everything crashed.

This is what happens when I try to run `pip`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_ma
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <mod
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 13,
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", lin
e>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources, six
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\__init__.py", l
_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\_
ne 1316, in <module>
    class MarkerEvaluation(object):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\_
ne 1320, in MarkerEvaluation
    'python_full_version': platform.python_version,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'python_version'
```

I get the same thing when I try to `import pandas` from the python shell. Oddly enough, when instead of import pandas i try to run `import pandas as pd`, I get this error:

```
In [3]: import pandas as pd
cannot import name hashtable
------------------------------------------
ImportError
<ipython-input-3-af55e7023913> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__ini
      5
      6 try:
----> 7     from . import hashtable, tslib
      8 except Exception:  # pragma: no co
      9     import sys

ImportError: cannot import name hashtable
```

Any idea how I can fix this without completely reinstalling Python and all my libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.8 removed some stuff. I solved my problems with pip (specifically pip install) by installing pip with `curl`

What worked for me was:
`cd ~/Downloads`
Downloading `get-pip.py`
`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
Then running it with python 3.8:
`python3.8 get-pip.py`

Solved it for me.

Source: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score -1):

You can find **platform.pyc** in your python folder, and delect it. OK, you will see it worked(because it will have a new **platform.pyc** right).